# Giving a lower bound for the number of (0,1)-matrices with row and column sum $\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics

Problem **16D** of A Course in Combinatorics (Van Lint-Wilson) is:

> Let $A(n,k)$ be number of (0,1)-matrices with row and column sum $k$. If $n$ is even, then
> $$A(n,\frac{n}{2}) \geq \frac{2^{n^2}}{n^{2n}}$$
> Show this by modifying the proof of the Corollary to Theorem 16.2.

I haven't had much luck "modifying the proof" of that corollary, and the hint at the end of the book didn't help me either. I really have no idea :(